# Gradiant Polys in Here-API Flutter?

Tags: flutter, here-api

Does the API for flutter support gradient polylines/polygons?

I've looked around the documents and forums but they're mainly related to the javascript API

Answer (score 1):

No, only solid colors for route/polylines, and separate solid color for its outline is supported currently.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @marco, HERE-flutter-api at the moment does not support for gradient polylines/polygons. It currently supports only solid colors for route and their outlines. Fore more info you can refer to the HERE flutter documentation. https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-navigate/4.13.4.0/dev_guide/index.html